# Почему такие странные имена в декомпилированом коде?

Tags: java, android, декомпиляция

Решил я декомпилировать код инстаграма и игры Bomb Squad, так как хотел посмотреть как реализовать некоторые вещи. Вот только когда я это сделал увидел следующую картину во всех файлах(и именах файлов тоже): все имена переменных, классов, методов названы странными именами.
[image: код инстаграма]

Я подумал что только разработчики инстаграма так делают, но когда декомпилировал Bomb Squad, увидел тоже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда декомпилировал свой код, все имена были прежнимы. Теперь не понимаю зачем так делают

Comment: Это обфуксация приложения. Погуглите на эту тему

Comment: Это делают для того, чтобы поменьше разных Петро лазило в чужой код и смотрело, как реализованы некоторые вещи. Однако не разработчики используют странные имена, а в процессе комиляции код запутывается (обфускируется)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Исходный код Java-программ преобразуется в байт-код после компиляции.
> Естественно, возможен и обратный процесс - декомпиляция. Существует
> огромное количество декомпиляторов, которые могут извлечь исходный код
> приложения в довольно хорошем качестве. **Все это ставит под угрозу
> интеллектуальную собственность автора программ и алгоритмов.**

Чтоб интеллектуальную собственность как-то защитить код шифруют (подвергают обфускации) на этапе компиляции. На этапе разработки имена классов и переменных вполне развернутые и понятные. На хабре про то, как делать так же есть [интересная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/436908/).